# Razorpage navigation leads to page self

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, razor

I am trying to navigate from the main Menu Index to my CreateJob file:

[image]

I am also needing to give the user Id with the link.
I tried 3 different ideas:

```
<li><a href="../Jobs/CreateJob?id=test">Job anlegen3</a></li>
<a asp-page="../Jobs/CreateJob?id=test">Job anlegen</a>
@Html.ActionLink("Job anlegen", "Jobs", "CreateJob", new { id = Model.userId })
```

The first one actually leads to the page I want but for some reason it looks like the controller behind the page seems to be disabled or not responding?

The other two just lead to the same page again and not away from it...

The last one generetaes this link:
https://localhost:44306/MainMenu?action=Jobs&controller=CreateJob

The create JOb simply does this:

```
 public class CreateJob : PageModel
    {

        public string userId = string.Empty;

        public async Task<IActionResult> OnGetUserId(string id)
        {
            // gets the url params 
            this.userId = id;
            return Page();

        }
    }
```

But this gets ignored with the first link...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
<li><a href="../Jobs/CreateJob?handler=UserId&id=test">Job anlegen3</a></li>
```

result:

[image]

Comment: Hello, while this does infact lead me to the correct page, it still doesnt trigger the stoppoint inside the controller the way youre having it. ...

Comment: @inno Do you set a breakpoint at  `OnGetUserId(string id)` ?

Comment: Yes, identical to how u did it...

Comment: @inno I will do a demo for you.

Comment: I try again, and the same work.

Comment: Man my bad - i had a namespace issue. The page did load but the controller was in a different namespace.. which is wired but was the issue. It works now with ur solution! thank you!

Answer (score 2):

This anchor tag helper format enters the `OnGetUserId` handler:

```
<a asp-page="/Jobs/CreateJob"
   asp-page-handler="UserId"
   asp-route-id="test">Job anlegen</a>
```

The `asp-page-handler` attribute in the anchor tag helper is found [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/tag-helpers/built-in/anchor-tag-helper?view=aspnetcore-7.0#asp-page-handler).

The above helper format produces the anchor tag listed in @Qing's answer (although without `..` at the start of the `href` attribute value):

```
<a href="/Jobs/CreateJob?id=test&handler=UserId">Job anlegen</a>
```

For future reference, the note just above the `asp-page-handler` attribute heading identifies the outcome you describe: "navigation leads to page self"

> If the referenced page doesn't exist, a link to the current page is generated using an ambient value from the request. No warning is indicated, except at the debug log level.

Comment: this does lead me to the right page but the controller I am having is never triggered

Comment: nevermind, I had a namespace issue it works now!